# Programmatically create Angular hierarchical injector

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, hierarchical

I currently use a `@Directive` with a set of providers to create an isolated injectable set of services/values for any component without it.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[my-isolated-directive]',
  providers: [MyHierarchicalService]
})
export class MyIsolatedDirective {}
```

```
<ng-container my-isolated-directive>
  <component-that-interacts-with-isolation></..>
  <component-that-requires-isolation></...>
</ng-container>
```

This works nicely but requires me to introduce a new set of code into the view where it arguably has nothing to do except open a new hierarchical injector with the service.

My question: Is it possible to do this programatically without the help of a directive? I know it's possible to manually create an injector with `Injector.create([MyHierarchicalService], parent)` but can I allow this injector to be natively used for child components?

It is unfeasible to simply move the `providers: [MyHierarchicalService]` into the `<component-that-requires-isolation>` component since multiple components within that isolation will require the same service. It can be seen as 'opening a space' in the hierarchical injector where below it, all components share the same service.

Example simplified stackblitz with my current solution: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zqxn4f

Actual directive with my isolated space when interested:
https://github.com/opf/openproject/pull/7042/files#diff-22f5fc2b9b761e556ed425d5e8b93fb4R70

Actual code using the directive solution:
https://github.com/opf/openproject/pull/7042/files#diff-09e0b8f2cf13d8ecc8ccc45872068580R7